# PDO fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) not returning values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First of all, this has something to do with **Login.**

I'm trying to store the values from the database into my $_SESSSION variables. At first, I tried to select all rows where username = user and password = password and so on.

If it returns > 0, then I tried to fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) to get the rows of it. 
The problem is, although it returns > 0 , it `FETCH_ASSOC` doesn't to return the values to me.

Here's what I tried so far.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_Save'])){
  $uname  = $_POST['username'];
  $pword  = $_POST['password'];
  $q = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password";
  $sql = $db->prepare($q);
  $sql->bindParam(":username",$uname);
  $sql->bindParam(":password",$pword);
  $sql->execute();
  $rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
  if($rows > 0){
  $rows2 = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  echo $rows2['userID'];
    $_SESSION['account'] = $rows2['userID'];
    $_SESSION['name']    = $rows2['firstName'];
 //echo" <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
  }
  else{
    echo"<script>alert('No user found!');</script>";
   // echo" <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";

  }
```

Comment: Remove `$rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
  if($rows > 0){` part from your code and use `$rows2 = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); if(count($rows2) > 0){`

Comment: Please do not keep your passwords in cleartext in the database - it's a huge privacy concern that the server owner can see everyones passwords. You can use [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](http://www.php.net/password_verify) to keep the passwords hashed (and unencryptable) in the database. If your PHP version is < 5.5 you can use [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) which will work in PHP >= 5.3.7. If your version is any older you should upgrade your installation as 5.3 dropped support back in august 2014.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PDO::FETCH_NUM:](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

> returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result
>   set, starting at column 0

So can't compare your array with your if condition below

```
$rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if($rows > 0){
```

In your code your are trying to `fetch data two times`. You can do it in single time

Use it as

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password";
$sql = $db->prepare($q);
$sql->bindParam(":username", $uname);
$sql->bindParam(":password", $pword);
$sql->execute();

$rows2 = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($rows2) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['account'] = $rows2['userID'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $rows2['firstName'];
    //echo" <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
} else {
    echo"<script>alert('No user found!');</script>";
    // echo" <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
}
```

Read about [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Plus you are storing plain password into your database

Read Password hashing technique

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: Thanks Saty! I never thought `FETCH_ASSOC` would return any number of  integer value.